# Should we accept Drupal DevOPs questions?

Tags: discussion

Generally, nowadays, it seems that Drupal dev-ops is an important topic.

I think that, since Drupal dev-ops becomes such useful and save so much time, we should accept questions about Drupal dev-ops.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of questions which you want to see allowed here? As we discussed the other day, only questions that require some specific knowledge of Drupal are ever going to be on topic here (the example given was that you won’t learn how to use Ansible or Docker here, for obvious reasons), but without knowing what policy/attitude you want to change in particular, it’s hard to imagine this going anywhere

Comment: It's like with PHP: Drupal is written in PHP, but plain PHP questions are off-topic for us. For that, there is already Stack Overflow, and we don't want to be a clone of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question that led to this, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/480616/creating-a-new-composerized-latest-drupal-project-with-local-drush-and-all-desir, was moved to the Unix site. It has been answered, with a lot of information that is tangential to Drupal, and specific to general server administration.

On one of the answers, you yourself linked to a question on the Dev-ops Stack Exchange site, declaring it to be useful background information to understand the answer.

And that's exactly the point - a place for everything, and everything in its place. We don't *need* to answer the general Dev-Ops questions here, because there are existing websites, indeed within this very network, which cater perfectly to those.

So going off the only example given in the comments, and the discussion you and I have had about this over the last few days, I'm going to go out on a limb and say: no, we don't need to relax the rules about Dev-Ops questions here. We already accept Drupal-specific Dev-Ops questions that otherwise fit into the guidelines, so there's nothing really to change anyway.

If you have a question about some Drupal-specific configuration of one of these tools, by all means ask it here. But if you have a general question, like your previous one about setting up an entire *nix development environment in one go, please don't ask that here. For a start it's actually much too broad for our format, but the main point being that not all of it relates to Drupal, so it's simply not a good question for a Drupal-specific Q+A site.